# SignalR: sometimes no data returns when trying to load images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, signalr, long-polling

Once in a while when loading image like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^
{
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:someImgUrl.jpg];
    if (data == nil)
    {
        NSLog( @"data is nil with img url:%@"  ,imgUrl);
        return;
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        img.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    });
});
```

my data is nil.
I used fiddler to sniff that, and saw that everytime it happened no request is shown in fiddler!

The only times it NEVER happens are

1. When I don't use SignalR client in my app.
2. Downloading the image synchronically:

   ```
   NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:someImgUrl.jpg ];
   img.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
   ```

The way I initialize SignalR is this:

```
NSString *listenurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", SERVICE_URL, @"/echo"];
mConnection = [SRConnection connectionWithURL:listenurl];
[mConnection setDelegate:self];
[mConnection start:[[SRLongPollingTransport alloc] init]];
```

Anyone else use signalR client in ios and exprience this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that problem only happens when SignalR listens with the same domain name to the server where you try to load images from.

So the (lame) solution so far that I found is buy a second domain and listen to that one.
Don't know why it happens though...

Comment: Maybe there's a concurrent request limit per domain that you can tweak via some setting?

Comment: @dfowler the server is IIS, is there some setting there? or maybe in the ios?